# Wrong Products count Display in magento 1.8.0.0 Admin

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

We are facing a issue as below.

The application is built on magento 1.8.0.0 version. The products have been associated to multiple categories. Some of the categories have more than 2000 products. When saving a category, The total counts of the products associated the category is drastically decreased. For ex: before saving the category, if the Category A products had 3000 products, Post saving this category A, the total products seen in the category A is 1000 or less than 1000.

Can someone please suggest the cause of this issue and if possible some solutions.

Quick answers are appreciated as the site is in critical stage.

Comment: This could be issue of max post data limit.I also faced same issue.If category has more than 1000 products then after save only 1000 product left.So please check you php.ini for post data limit.

Answer (score 0):

Seems so you have an issue with the indexer.

What happens if you do a full reindex? Does the amount of products come back?